# Python/Scrapy/ - Scraping from Arstechnica

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

Im trying to scrape content from the page https://arstechnica.com/ using Python, scrapy, selenium and phantomjs. My program searches the website with a given argument, and extracts all the links to the articles with the given keyword. The problem is that there could be so much articles so that they wount show up in 1 page ( example when searching for heartbleed https://arstechnica.com/search/?ie=UTF-8&q=heartbleed ). My program should now load the second page and continue extracting links to the articles, and repeat that process until there are no more pages left. The thing is, i have no idea how to implement that. I am open to suggestions!

Note :
- there is no next page button
- clicking a new site( on the index at the bottom of the site) doesn´t generate a new url, so i cant tell scrapy to open a new page

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look in Chrome developer tools / Network tab, it seems like the results are provided by call to Google API custom search via https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element, which returns results in JSON. You can see there URL parameters passed and basically use that for your `start_urls`.